# Is there any Dictionary Library for C?

Tags: c, dictionary

I would like to know if there is any dictionary library for C. A dictionary library, literally (It has nothing to do with python dictionaries (hashmaps)). With all the words of the english language, and with tools like...

"I want to print all words that begins with C and end with Y".

I'll not google it, because I really want to know your opinion, if there is any that is specifically good.

Thank you!

Comment: So you're just looking for a text file?

Comment: haha.. My question sounds silly, I know. But, not exactly a text file. I could take a text file with all the english words and use C to make all kinds of things with it, but there could be any function that could bring me words by meaning, synonyms, etc.

Comment: *"I'll not google it, because I really want to know your opinion, if there is any that is specifically good."* - So, essentially, you don't feel like doing your own research to narrow the candidates down?

Comment: Do you have any experience with SQL? Because all you need is a database populated with english the words.

Comment: On almost any Linux distribution you can use the dictionaries provided in `/usr/share/dict/`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start by looking at [Aspell](http://aspell.net/).  While it mostly functions as a spell-checker, Aspell also has support for using multiple dictionaries at once and intelligently handling personal dictionaries when more than one Aspell process is open at once. I don't believe you have to be connected to the Internet to use it as well.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Main_page) might also be of any help. There are *a lot* of localized variations to support different languages and there will probably be a way to ask them to support your language of interest, if it is not already there.

Comment: Even though it's essentially dead...

Answer (score 1):

There's amazing [Wordnik API](http://developer.wordnik.com), if you don't mind using Internet for this task. The API is fairly easy and supports regex search. The method you are looking for is [`/words.{format}/search/{query}`](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs#!/words/search_words)

It also has methods to retrieve meanings ([`/word.{format}/{word}/definitions`](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs#!/word/get_definitions)), synonyms ([`/word.{format}/{word}/relatedWords`](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs#!/word/get_related_words)), and many other things.

There currently are no C wrappers, although it's very easy to use API directly with libcurl and any JSON or XML parser.